# How to append a list with a newline?

Tags: python, list

In the following code I am updating a list with two items by appending to it from within a for loop. I need a newline to be added after appending each string but I can't seem to be able to do it.

I thought it would have been:

```
lines = []
for i in range(10):

    line = ser.readline()
    if line:
        lines.append(line + '\n')             #'\n' newline 
        lines.append(datetime.now())
```

But this only adds the '\n' as a string. I have also tried the same without without the quotes, but no luck.

I am getting this:

```
['leftRaw; 928090;   0;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;      0.00;  0.00;\n', datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 25, 23, 48, 4, 517000), '\r\x00rightRaw; 928090;   0;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;\n', datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 25, 23, 48, 4, 519000), '\r\x00leftRaw; 928091;   0;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00)]
```

But I want this:

```
['leftRaw; 928090;   0;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;\n', 
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 25, 23, 48, 4, 517000), 
'\r\x00rightRaw; 928090;   0;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;\n', 
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 25, 23, 48, 4, 519000)]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is that tagged as [tag:b]? :P

Comment: And what happened when you tried the second snippet?

Comment: I sent the question half done by mistake, I have now completed the question. Apologies for that.

Comment: Can you post the result that you're getting, and an example of the result you're expecting?

Comment: @Steve OK. I think I had the same question as you at some time, but I cannot seem to find it, which means I was talking nonsense, thus didn't post it. What is exactly the thing you wish to do? I mean, of course it will add it to the string. If you want, you can always append a new list item, which will be a newline.

Comment: Updated my post to include outcome and expected outcome

Comment: See my updated post. I want each line to be appear underneath each-other, as one vertical column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the issue by appending `datetime.now` to the list as a string on every frame using the `strftime` method. I was then able to add newlines with `lines = '\n'.join(lines)`. See code below for the working code.

```
lines = []
for frame in range(frames):
    line = ser.readline()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
        lines.append(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

lines = '\n'.join(lines)

dataFile.write('%s'%(lines))
```

This gives me the desired output of each list item on a new line e.g.

```
['leftRaw; 928090;   0;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;\n', 
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 25, 23, 48, 4, 517000), 
'\r\x00rightRaw; 928090;   0;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;  0.00;\n', 
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 25, 23, 48, 4, 519000)']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add all items to the list, then use .join() function to add new line between each item in the list:

```
for i in range(10):
    line = ser.readline()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
        lines.append(datetime.now())
final_string = '\n'.join(lines)
```

Comment: I am afraid the OP didn't ask for that.. :/

Comment: This does not match OP's desired code, since this would add a newline after datetimes as well.

Comment: Thanks, it is a newline after each append not just the one. Using your method I get this error: TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, datetime.datetime found. Tried converting the datetime to str but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `lines` list is simple being printed in its entirety. The `\n` you see is only printing as an indicator that there are in fact new-lines. See this smaller example:

```
In [18]: print ['asdf' + '\n\n'] + [datetime.now()],
['asdf\n\n', datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 25, 15, 32, 5, 955895)]
In [19]: a = ['asdf' + '\n\n', datetime.now()]
In [20]: print a[0]
asdf

In [21]: print a
['asdf\n\n', datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 25, 15, 37, 14, 330440)]

In [22]:
```

Comment: I see. I can't seem to convert datetime.datetime to a string